# Pi B 2 Segmentation fault result from airmon-ng - Why?

Tags: pi-2

This is my first post here and I'm a major noob to this RPi stuff. I'm experimenting with aircrack-ng on my own network to test it's weaknesses and want to use my Pi to do it. I installed a fresh and updated image of Raspbian and installed the aircrack-ng suite.

I have the Pi running with an Edimax wifi dongle and it is connected to my router with an Ethernet cable so that I can ssh in and mess with the wifi without interrupting the ssh (duh).

I'm getting "Segmentation fault" when I run `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` as well as a bunch of other messages I don't understand. I'll include the text from the terminal below which begins after a clean restart. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Here's the output of iwconfig:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"my_network"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 58:EF:68:0F:76:91
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Here's my terminal capture:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo airmon-ng

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy0    wlan0           rtl8192cu       Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo airmon-ng check kill

Killing these processes:

  PID Name
  284 dhcpcd
  289 wpa_supplicant
  334 wpa_supplicant

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo airmon-ng start wlan0


PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy0    wlan0           rtl8192cu       Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

Newly created monitor mode interface wlan0mon is *NOT* in monitor mode.
Removing non-monitor wlan0mon interface...

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  154.895051] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.058275] Process iw (pid: 859, stack limit = 0x2c4890bd)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.067282] Stack: (0xd7397bd8 to 0xd7398000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.075036] 7bc0:                                                       c09f78a0 d8ce4cc0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.089817] 7be0: ffffc74c d8ce4cc0 d7397c3c d7397bf8 c05b1aa8 c05a7c28 c00d3e2c d7397bfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.104720] 7c00: d7397bfc d7397c10 c05aa250 ca132103 00000001 bf298bdc d8ce4cc0 d8d08b00

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.119870] 7c20: d8ce4cc0 c09e7028 d7958000 00000000 d7397c4c d7397c40 c05bfb28 c05b189c

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.135024] 7c40: d7397c64 d7397c50 bf257cfc c05bfb1c bf298bdc bf2a4b3c d7397cf4 d7397c68

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.150187] 7c60: c05f6eb4 bf257c68 bf297e34 d7397cfc c0057ff0 00000014 c0a668b0 d7397cfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.165372] 7c80: 00000000 60000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 d7397c94 d7397c94 5d2152a8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.180859] 7ca0: ab80035b d8d08b00 d8d08b10 d8d08b14 d7958000 c0a668b0 d78d2000 d68c2000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.196781] 7cc0: d7397cfc ca132103 c00580cc 00000000 c09e7028 c05f6c5c d8ce4cc0 d8d08b00

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.212935] 7ce0: 00000000 c09e7028 d7397d44 d7397cf8 c05f5eb0 c05f6c68 c018cc4c 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.229430] 7d00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ca132103

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.246070] 7d20: d7397d44 c0a6a488 d8ce4cc0 d8ce4cc0 0000001c c09e89bc d7397d5c d7397d48

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.262893] 7d40: c05f6c48 c05f5dbc dad89800 d8da7400 d7397d94 d7397d60 c05f55dc c05f6c24

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.280036] 7d60: 7fffffff ca132103 d7397f4c d8ce4cc0 c09e7028 0000001c d8da7400 d7397f44

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.297283] 7d80: 00000000 00000000 d7397dfc d7397d98 c05f5a24 c05f5440 d7397e1c ca132103

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.314539] 7da0: d7397f44 00000000 c09e7028 d7397e18 00000000 0000001c d68f1280 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.331784] 7dc0: 0000035b 00000000 00000000 ca132103 007c31d4 d7397f44 00000000 c09e7028

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.349036] 7de0: d8bbf480 00000000 00000000 d7397edc d7397e0c d7397e00 c058a550 c05f5740

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.366289] 7e00: d7397f2c d7397e10 c058ad3c c058a538 d7397e3c 00000040 00000000 007c32a0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.383547] 7e20: 0000001c d7397e30 c01423b4 c01077c0 d8bbf620 c0724000 d8bbf620 d8d057e0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.400804] 7e40: 00000054 006200ca 00000021 00031000 d68fc000 d68fc000 00000000 00000010

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.418059] 7e60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 d8c24858 00000000 ca132103 d7397fb0 d6902a00

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.435306] 7e80: 00000017 00031098 d8c24820 c06d41a4 d7397ef4 d7397ea0 c06d41a4 c005f6d8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.452556] 7ea0: 20000013 c09fd8d8 c0070f44 dacc2710 d8be0a18 d8bbf620 d7397ee4 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.469806] 7ec0: 00000000 00000100 20000013 c09ec240 00000017 c09e7028 c06d400c 00031098

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.487058] 7ee0: d7397fb0 00000028 d7397fac d7397ef8 c001ab44 c0192964 d7397f14 ca132103

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.504308] 7f00: c0192964 c09e7028 d8bbf480 00000000 beb19548 c00091a4 d7396000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.521589] 7f20: d7397f94 d7397f30 c058be00 c058ab3c 00000000 00000000 d7397f64 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.538857] 7f40: fffffff7 d7397e5c 0000000c 00000001 00000000 00000000 d7397e24 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.556121] 7f60: d7397f8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ca132103 007c31c8 007c8448

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.573388] 7f80: 007c8500 00000128 d7397fa4 d7397f98 c058be60 c058bdb0 00000000 d7397fa8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.590651] 7fa0: c0009000 c058be50 007c31c8 007c8448 00000003 beb19548 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.607926] 7fc0: 007c31c8 007c8448 007c8500 00000128 b6f08000 beb198cf 007c8500 beb197c4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.625198] 7fe0: 0000006c beb19500 b6eed5bc b6e68980 60000010 00000003 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.920914] Code: e1d300b2 e0600005 ebee1453 e89da8f0 (e7f001f2)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  155.981467] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.148723] Process RTW_CMD_THREAD (pid: 332, stack limit = 0xe4581df8)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.158792] Stack: (0xd7081d40 to 0xd7082000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.166568] 1d40: c04c34cc c015f608 c09e7028 da5c2000 00000001 00000000 0000004c 00000005

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.181492] 1d60: d7081d84 d7081d70 c04c24bc c015f2a8 00000040 c09e7028 d7081dcc d7081d88

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.196740] 1d80: c04c35a8 c04c24a8 c004aee4 d8c30a00 80000400 00000040 00000000 978bc4c3

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.212310] 1da0: c00d3e2c 00000001 00000009 d8c30a00 80000400 da5c2000 d8f70cc0 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.227910] 1dc0: d7081e3c d7081dd0 bf35d328 c04c352c 0000004c 00000000 d8c30a00 00000001

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.243521] 1de0: 000001f4 c09f0160 c09e7028 dcf88000 dcf85000 0000f04c d8f70d44 00000001

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.259198] 1e00: 00000001 00000000 00000005 0000004c bf35d600 c09e7028 dcf88224 d795b000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.275185] 1e20: dcf86000 dcf85000 dcf86458 bf37dba8 d7081e6c d7081e40 bf35d600 bf35d1d0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.291531] 1e40: d7081e50 00000001 00000000 bf37dba8 00000008 978bc4c3 c06cf724 dcf85000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.308113] 1e60: d7081e7c d7081e70 bf31c2ec bf35d5c0 d7081e9c d7081e80 bf359618 bf31c2d0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.325016] 1e80: 00000000 dcf85000 dcf88224 dcf86440 d7081eb4 d7081ea0 bf359cb0 bf3594d8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.342090] 1ea0: dcf85000 dcf85000 d7081ecc d7081eb8 bf360488 bf359650 00000002 dcf85000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.359283] 1ec0: d7081ee4 d7081ed0 bf3339b0 bf360450 00000000 dcf8808c d7081efc d7081ee8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.376542] 1ee0: bf3339fc bf333964 dcf85000 dcf85000 d7081f14 d7081f00 bf333ce4 bf3339d8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.393790] 1f00: 00000003 d78d3200 d7081f3c d7081f18 bf318b5c bf333bf8 bf318ae0 d8ce79c0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.411055] 1f20: dcf88000 dcf86440 dcf86000 dcf85000 d7081f7c d7081f40 bf316a64 bf318aec

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.428312] 1f40: d7be5680 00000040 dcf8644c d78d3200 c0042820 d7be5680 d682d7c0 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.445556] 1f60: dcf85000 bf3168bc d7be5698 d72b7c30 d7081fac d7081f80 c0042fac bf3168c8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.462796] 1f80: ffffffff d682d7c0 c0042e90 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.480035] 1fa0: 00000000 d7081fb0 c00090ac c0042e9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.497269] 1fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.514500] 1fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:17 ...
 kernel:[  156.870256] Code: e5935000 e3550000 0a00004d e5943014 (e7950003)
Segmentation fault

WARNING: unable to start monitor mode, please run "airmon-ng check kill"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo airmon-ng
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not foundMessage from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.058275] Process iw (pid: 859, stack limit = 0x2c4890bd)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.067282] Stack: (0xd7397bd8 to 0xd7398000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.075036] 7bc0:                                                       c09f78a0 d8ce4cc0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.089817] 7be0: ffffc74c d8ce4cc0 d7397c3c d7397bf8 c05b1aa8 c05a7c28 c00d3e2c d7397bfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.104720] 7c00: d7397bfc d7397c10 c05aa250 ca132103 00000001 bf298bdc d8ce4cc0 d8d08b00

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.119870] 7c20: d8ce4cc0 c09e7028 d7958000 00000000 d7397c4c d7397c40 c05bfb28 c05b189c

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.135024] 7c40: d7397c64 d7397c50 bf257cfc c05bfb1c bf298bdc bf2a4b3c d7397cf4 d7397c68

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.150187] 7c60: c05f6eb4 bf257c68 bf297e34 d7397cfc c0057ff0 00000014 c0a668b0 d7397cfc

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.165372] 7c80: 00000000 60000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 d7397c94 d7397c94 5d2152a8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.180859] 7ca0: ab80035b d8d08b00 d8d08b10 d8d08b14 d7958000 c0a668b0 d78d2000 d68c2000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.196781] 7cc0: d7397cfc ca132103 c00580cc 00000000 c09e7028 c05f6c5c d8ce4cc0 d8d08b00

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.212935] 7ce0: 00000000 c09e7028 d7397d44 d7397cf8 c05f5eb0 c05f6c68 c018cc4c 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  155.229430] 7d00: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ca132103

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  6 20:02:16 ...
 kernel:[  1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: actually there are two raspbian versions: stretch (debian 9) and buster (debian 10). With buster my kodi does not work, perhaps you get it to work with stretch, i dont know.  Check `lsb_release -a && uname -a` for release version.  Also it might be that your wifi-adapter is not able to go to monitor-mode to capture packages see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8578/enable-monitor-mode-in-rtl8188cus-realtek-wifi-usb-dongle.

Comment: It does appear that the dongle won't go into monitor mode, from the terminal dump, above. I am running Buster (debian 10). I will try the USB wifi dongle on a laptop that I have successfully been using aircrack-ng on to see if it is the hardware, or if it's a driver issue. Thanks, Alex for your comment.

Comment: I moved to Stretch (debian 9) and could run airmon-ng without any "Segmentation fault" errors. After a lot of reading, it seems that the Edimax EW-7811Un wifi dongle doesn't go into listening mode with the drivers included with Raspbian Stretch or Buster. This may just not be a good USB dongle to use with a Pi for monitoring purposes. Does anyone have a driver that would make this work?

Comment: you could try the realtek dkms depending on your chipset