# Wireless Card - RPi4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, wireless

I went ahead and used the command to check what the Wireless Card was of the RPi4, and I got the code to be VL805 by VIA Technologies, Inc. Is this wireless card compatible with airmon-ng? If not, what should I do to get airmon-ng to work? I am trying to change my wireless card to a monitor mode.

Comment: That's the USB controller. The wifi controller is a Cypress / Broadcom product. No idea if it's compatible with your software.

Comment: How does it fail when you try it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sniff your neighbors WiFi, the wireless chip must support **monitor mode**. The built-in WiFi on a Raspberry Pi does not support it. So you are without luck. You can check it with:

```
rpi ~$ iw list
```

and look for `Supported interface modes:` in the longish output. Have a look at [Enable monitor mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103520/79866) for further information about this.

Answer (score 2):

The dmesg log shows that the driver is loaded for a BCM4345/6 chip.  It may be worth you checking this on your board as the RPT/RPF have not stated what this chip is as far as I know (and it's not in the certification documentation).

This note from Kali Linux [here](https://www.kali.org/news/raspberry-pi-4-and-kali/) states that you can get:

> on-board wifi monitor mode & frame injection support

Running `airmon-ng` will report what it thinks the chip is and running `airmon-ng check` will tell any software clashes.