# Does the Raspberry Pi 4 chip set allow monitor mode?

Tags: networking

I tried to run the command to test if my device supports monitor mode,

```
airmon-ng start wlan-0
```

and this is the error is received,

```
ERROR adding monitor mode interface: command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Apparently, I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 model B for network scanning, but it does not support monitor mode for this to happen. Can anyone suggest me a way to have this mode on my device.

Comment: Off the top of my head: did you try running that with `sudo`, and is your interface really called `wlan-0`, and not `wlan0`? And then, there's always the option to buy a USB stick with a recommended chipset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the chip configuration on the RasPi with:

```
rpi ~$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
--- snip ---
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * P2P-client
             * P2P-GO
             * P2P-device
--- snap ---
```

There is no **monitor mode** available, so you are out of luck with sniffing WiFi networks with a Raspberry Pi. There is a project [nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) on github that patches the WiFi firmware to make the monitor mode available. Seems not to be an easy task but you may have a look at it.

For some additional information you can also look at [Enable monitor mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103520/79866).

You may consider to purchase an additional USB/WiFi dongle that supports monitor mode.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the aircrack program with my Raspberry Pi 4 8 gig approximately 1 week ago. I had no issues setting the internal WiFi interface into monitor mode.

Then again I was running Kali on the pi hardware. Although that shouldn't matter I don't think.

Comment: My only guess is that kali comes with the correct kernel to support monitor mode

Comment: I tested it on RaspberryOS RPI-4 4GB and could not enter monitor mode.
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I got the wireless card in my Raspberry Pi 4B into monitor mode by running these commands:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down && \
sudo iw wlan0 set monitor control && \
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

Comment: Are you sure? tried this and got an error on the second command

Comment: I thought it worked for me before. Now when I run iwconfig it shows the card is in monitor mode, but the actual operations are not working. I recommend this wireless card if you're on a budget. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01GC8XH0S

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a PAU09, from Amazon, that does a fine monitoring