# Local Wireless NIC Monitor Mode

Tags: networking, pi-4

I was wondering if anyone here has been able to get local the local wireless NIC on monitor mode on RASPIAN 11? (pi4)

Comment: it's been asked and answered before - probably many times - searching this forum I found [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121884/does-the-raspberry-pi-4-chip-set-allow-monitor-mode)